# Select several multiple-line strings

Tags: regex

Wanna replace `//` in `<%-- --%>` without influence `//` outside `<%-- --%>` by regex.

Here is the example:

```
<%-- //1 --%>
<%-- //2
//2 --%>
<%-- //3
//3
//3 --%>
//4
```

How could I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since no language is specified, I’d do this in Powershell with the `-replace` operator, which uses regex matching.

```
$s = @'
<%-- //1 --%>
<%-- //2
//2 --%>
<%-- //3
//3
//3 --%>
//4
'@
$s -replace '(?s)(?<=<%-{2}.*?)//(?=.*?-{2}%>)'
```

`$s` or your string is expected to be a single string. You will need a single line modifier (`s`) in order for `.` to match new line characters. Some languages will not support variable length matches using `*` inside lookaheads. If that is the case for you, you can just include them as part of the match as a capture group and rebuild your string using them.

Comment: This appears to be exhibiting a similar issue to my solution. I'm actually finding it quite tricky. You have to do something to make the lookahead traverse more than one line.

Comment: @AndrewDavis, I don't agree. Mine does traverse multiple lines as long as the input string is a single string rather than an array of strings. If it is an array, you can simply join the strings with your favorite new line character. If you add `//5` to the end of the string in your example, the `//` are removed. They are not in mine. In the posted example, only `//4` should remain untouched, yes?

Comment: Ah you're right actually. He mentioned he's using "ant regexp-replace". Not sure what that is, or if he can stringify it like you did.

Comment: Combined your precious thinking, the recent progress is on https://regex101.com/r/qD5Yzc/4. Suppose "//123321" should be excluded but not. Considered as a boundary's vague.

Comment: It's done by this regex: (?<=<%--(?:(?!<%--|--%>)[\w\W])*)\/\/(?=(?:(?!<%--|--%>)[\w\W])*--%>)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to grab the "//" within "<%-- --%>" and not the ones outside

I think you want a `negative lookbehind` and `negative lookahead`

```
(?<!%>\n)\/\/(?![\d]\n<%)
```

Implementation would vary by language you're using.

Note: this is making some assumptions on format, but it's likely close to what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I tried this way but still failed. Could you have any idea to use negative lookbehind and negative lookahead to match "//" in the multi-line "<%----%>". Pick out 3 "//" on the example above, but not 4 "//".

Comment: Not sure, it works in Regex101 for me using the test example you've provided.


https://regex101.com/r/qD5Yzc/1


Are you able to give some more info on what language or environment you are using?

Comment: Sorry for the test example, may you add "//5" below "//4" and the "//5" won't be excluded  in Regex101. By the way, I am trying to use ant replace-regexp to do something.

Comment: Tough one, I can't seem to do much better than this. Seems to be a limitation of looking ahead multiple lines... Or perhaps someone who knows more could chime in. https://regex101.com/r/qD5Yzc/2